# Chart.js x axis date-time formatting fails

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I am using Python and Flask to get data from a service and Chart.js to chart values over time. I cannot get the xAxes time formatting to work in Chart.js. I'm new to JavaScript so maybe its something simple like a missing comma but I do not think so.

My python was passing a datetime object to the JavaScript. I thought maybe chart.js needed a string so I created a static python function to provide a few string dates but it produced the same result.

Chart.js script with Jinja2 templating:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chart.js Example</title>
    <!-- import plugin script -->
    <script src={{ url_for('static', filename="vendor/chart.min.js") }}></script>
    <script src={{ url_for('static', filename="vendor/moment.min.js") }}></script>
    <!--<script src='static/vendor/chart.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{ url_for('static', filename="chartStyle.css") }}> -->

</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple Line Chart</h1>


<div class="container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>DateTime</th>

        </tr>
        {% for itme in labels %}
            <tr><td>{{itme}}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
 <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    // define the chart data
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line', //types: bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: [
                {% for item in labels %}
                    new Date('{{item}}'), //I've tried inserting a string instead of date object
                    //'{{item}}',
                {% endfor %}],
            datasets: [{
                label: '{{ legend }}',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(117, 4, 28)',
                borderWidth:1,
                hoverBorderWidth:3,
                hoverBorderColor:'#000',
                data: [{% for item in values %}
                    {{item}},
                {% endfor %}],
            }]
        },
        options:{
            title:{
                display:true,
                text:'test string date time',
                fontSize:25,
            },
            legend:{
                //display:false //to hide legend
                position:'right',
                labels:{
                    fontColor:'#000'
                }
            },
            tooltips:{
                //enabled:false,
            },
            scales:{
                yAxes:[{
                    scaleLabel:{
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'mg/m3',
                        fontColor: '#000',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:25
                    }
                }],
                xAxes:[{
                    Type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        parser: 'HH:mm:ss a',   //these formatting values do nothing, I've tried a few different ones
                        unit: 'second',   //I have tried minutes and hours too, same result
                        displayFormats: {
                            'millisecond': 'HH:mm:ss a',   //I have tried without the 'a' too, same result
                            'second': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'minute': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'hour': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'day': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'week': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'month': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'quarter': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                            'year': 'HH:mm:ss a',
                        }
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        source: 'auto'
                    },
                    scaleLabel:{
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Recording Time',
                        fontColor: '#000',                        
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:25
                }
                }]
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            elements: {
                point:{
                    radius: 0
                },
                line: {
                    tension: 0
                }
            },
        }

    });





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Python function with testing data:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, request
stringDate_bp5 = Blueprint('stringDate_bp5', __name__,
    template_folder='../templates',
    static_folder='../stringDate/static/vendor/', static_url_path='/stringDate/static/vendor/')


@stringDate_bp5.route("")
def stringDate():
    #reading1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 19, 13, 36, 29, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
    labels = ['2019-12-19T13:36:29-08:00', '2019-12-19T13:36:59-08:00', '2019-12-19T13:37:29-08:00', '2019-12-19T13:37:59-08:00', '2019-12-19T13:38:29-08:00']
    values = [0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.08, 0.05]
    legend = 'Test String Dates'
    return render_template('chart2.html', values=values, labels=labels, legend=legend)
```

output:

[Chart output with Day, Month, date, year, time, UTC offset, timezone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKu6B.png)
The X axes labels should just be time but no matter what I try the labels stay in the default format shown above.

Comment: You capitalized `Type: 'time'`.  Change the property to lowercase!

Comment: Good catch but that was not the issue. Although the Chart.js docs show type: 'time', when I change the case from "Type" to "type" the chart does not even load. The X axis data is loaded as Labels - mayby it need to be x or t???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart config looks just fine after change `Type: 'time'` to `type: 'time'`.  You can run the version below, which substitutes your Python template variables.

Here are some other things to check

- After correcting the `type` typo, look for console errors.
- Make sure moment.js is loading correctly.
- Check the versions of moment.js and Chart.js (example below uses 2.26.0 and 2.9.3 respectively).
- Provide the actual HTML source (instead of the template), because if it's still broken it implies something wrong with the templating/passing values.

```js
const config = {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line', //types: bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [new Date('2019-12-19T13:36:29-08:00'), new Date('2019-12-19T13:36:59-08:00'), new Date('2019-12-19T13:37:29-08:00'), new Date('2019-12-19T13:37:59-08:00'), new Date('2019-12-19T13:38:29-08:00')],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Test String Dates',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(117, 4, 28)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
      hoverBorderColor: '#000',
      data: [0.05, 0.07, 0.15, 0.08, 0.05],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'test string date time',
      fontSize: 25,
    },
    legend: {
      //display:false //to hide legend
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#000'
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      //enabled:false,
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'mg/m3',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: 25
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'HH:mm:ss a', //these formatting values do nothing, I've tried a few different ones
          unit: 'second', //I have tried minutes and hours too, same result
          displayFormats: {
            'millisecond': 'HH:mm:ss a', //I have tried without the 'a' too, same result
            'second': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'minute': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'hour': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'day': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'week': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'month': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'quarter': 'HH:mm:ss a',
            'year': 'HH:mm:ss a',
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          source: 'auto'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Recording Time',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: 25
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    },
  }

};

const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: The typo in Type caused Chart.js to make a standard line chart and ignore time formatting. But my routing to moment.js was incorrect in flask so when I fixed the typo the chart could not load because it needed moment to render the chart. Thanks Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Note: in `displayFormats` fields, remove the quote signs, e.g:

```
...scales: {
    x: {
      type: "time",
        time: { 
          /* unit: "hour", // "day" */ /* auto selected */ 
          tooltipFormat: 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',  
          displayFormats: { 
            second: 'HH:mm:ss',
            minute: 'HH:mm:ss',
            hour: 'HH:mm',
            day: 'dd-MMM',
            month: 'MMM-yyyy',
            year: 'yyyy'
          }
        }, ...
```